# Function Definition/Declaration Using Function Pointer `typedef` in C

Tags: c, syntax, typedef, function-declaration, function-definition

UPDATE:

This was just something stupid. My PC crashed a few minutes after this, and after restart it throws the same error as to everyone else... Even when I go back to the original version using GIT. I guess something got messed up in the PCs RAM? XD

In C, can a function pointer type be used to declare and define a function?

I did this by mistake, but it worked as expected without throwing any warnings:

init.h:

```
typedef bool (*InitFunc)(void);
```

init.c:

```
#include <init.h>
#include <moduleX.h>

InitFunc initFuncs[N];

bool init(void)
{    
    ...

    initFuncs[n] = &moduleX_Init;

    ...
}

bool initTask(void* Args)
{

    initFuncs[n]();

}
```

moduleX.h:

```
#include <init.h>

InitFunc moduleX_Init(void);
```

moduleX.c:

```
#include <moduleX.h>

InitFunc moduleX_Init(void)
{
    
    ...
        
    return true;
}
```

As you can see, I defined the function `moduleX_Init` using the `typedef` of the function pointer. It compiled using GCC (arm-none-eabi-gcc) without even an warning and worked as expected.

I only did this by mistake, but when I noticed it, I was wondering if this is actually a compliant way to declare a function or it just happens to work with GCC.

EDIT:

If I do the declaration like this `InitFunc moduleX_Init;`, then I get the following error:

> incompatible types when assigning to type InitFunc {aka _Bool
> (*)(void)}' from type '_Bool'

So it seams, that when used in variable declarations, the function pointer types work as if they were a `typedef` of the return type. Is this standard behavior, or just the particularity of GCC?

Comment: You can't assign between function pointers of different types. That's non-compliant with the C language. You can do so with an explicit cast, but you still have to call the function using its correct type.

Comment: Why doesn't `moduleX_Init` just return a `bool`?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use a function pointer typedef to declare or define a function.  You can use use to use function pointer typedefs to specify the type of the return value and arguments.

You are declaring moduleX_Init to return a function pointer.  Is that what you wanted?  @SergeyA already gave you the warning for the assignment and here is the warning you get for moduleX_Init (gcc 8.3.0-6 without any arguments other the input file):

```
1.c: In function ‘moduleX_Init’:
1.c:6:9: warning: returning ‘int’ from a function with return type ‘InitFunc’ {aka ‘_Bool (*)(void)’} makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]                                                                            
  return true;
         ^~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is malformed, and there is no way it could have been compiled without warnings. Here is the one I am getting with your code:

```
<source>: In function 'init': <source>:11:18: warning: assignment to 'InitFunc' {aka '_Bool (*)(void)'} from incompatible pointer type '_Bool (* (*)(void))(void)' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

Your declaration

```
typedef bool (*InitFunc)(void);

InitFunc moduleX_Init(void);
```

declares a function which returns a pointer to function. By itself, there is nothing wrong with it, but when you try to use it like this:

```
initFuncs[n] = &moduleX_Init;
```

You are assigning function pointers with incompatible signatures, as `initFuncs[n]` has a type `bool (*)(void)`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was thinking too. But I get no warnings.

Comment: It is also strange, because, how can I have a function returning a function pointer like this?

Comment: @Cerike it is not strange at all. Functions are first class citizens in C, so you can return pointers to them from functions as much as pointers to any other types. Sometimes, such functions are called higher order functions.

Comment: That's not what I meant, I mean its strange, that it behaves like this for me, because in this way, I cant have a function returning a function pointer.

Comment: @Cerike not sure what you mean. Most certainly you can't have a function returning a pointer to function, you just can't use it when a function returning `bool` is required.

Answer (score 0):

> In C, can a function pointer type be used to declare and define a function?

No. A function pointer is just a pointer. You can use it to call the function is points to, and for any case a pointer can be used

> I did this by mistake, but it worked as expected without throwing any warnings

Well, as for the "*any warnings*"  part compilers here disagree with you. For this line:

```
    typedef bool (*InitFunc)(void);
```

**`clang 10` compiler says**

```
dsp$ clang -c min.c
min.c:2:16: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
typedef bool (*InitFunc)(void);
               ^
min.c:2:9: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
typedef bool (*InitFunc)(void);
~~~~~~~ ^
min.c:2:14: error: function cannot return function type 'int (void)'
typedef bool (*InitFunc)(void);
             ^
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
```

**And `gcc 9.3` says**

```
dsp$ gcc -c min.c
min.c:2:15: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token
    2 | typedef bool (*InitFunc)(void);
      |               ^
```

As for the part "*it worked as expected*" what your expectations were?

#### Another similar typedef

```
typedef int(*Pfri)(int);
```

This is fairly common stuff and declares the name `Pfri` as a `pointer` to a `function` that returns an `int` and takes one `int` as argument, and this time the compilers will be happy with it.

#### C Example using this

```
#define N 10
#include    <stdio.h>

typedef int(*Pfri)(int);

int plus3(int i) { return i*3; };
int plus4(int i) { return i*4; };

int main(void)
{
    Pfri    initFunc[N];
    printf("fills array of function pointers\n");
    for( int i = 0; i<N; i+=2 )
        initFunc[i] = plus4, initFunc[1+i] = plus3;
    printf("\
For odd indexes, function is \"int plus3(int i) { return i*3; };\"\n\
For even  indexes, function is \"int plus4(int i) { return i*4; };\"\n\
Array has %d functions\n", N);
    for( int i=0; i<N; i+=1 )
        printf("f(%d)=%d\n", i,initFunc[i](i) );
    return 0;
}
```

This program:

- takes the above mentioned typedef and declares an array of them.
- declares 2 functions compatible with this typedefed name
- fills the array with pointers to the functions
- calls each one and displays the results

#### Output

```
fills array of function pointers
For odd indexes, function is "int plus3(int i) { return i*3; };"
For even  indexes, function is "int plus4(int i) { return i*4; };"
Array has 10 functions
f(0)=0
f(1)=3
f(2)=8
f(3)=9
f(4)=16
f(5)=15
f(6)=24
f(7)=21
f(8)=32
f(9)=27
```